# I want to insert data into mysql database using PDO of PHP. But the data is not inserted

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to insert data into mysql database using PDO of PHP. But the data is not inserted. I used PDO before, but did not face any problem. But in the following case, I do not understand where i do wrong. Can anyone please help me? Output is showing well with echo.

```
<?php

include 'includes/config.php';

$name1 = $_POST['name1'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['city']; 
$state = $_POST['state'];
$zip_code = $_POST['zip_code'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$fiance = $_POST['fiance'];
$wedding_date = $_POST['wedding_date'];
$number_of_guest = $_POST['number_of_guest'];

$radio = $_POST['radio']; 
if($radio=='on') $radio = 'yes'; 

$newspaper = $_POST['newspaper']; 
if($newspaper=='on') $newspaper = 'yes';

$facebook = $_POST['facebook']; 
if($facebook=='on') $facebook = 'yes';

$website = $_POST['website']; 
if($website=='on') $website = 'yes';

$hear_by_other = $_POST['hear_by_other']; 
if($hear_by_other=='on') $hear_by_other = 'yes';

$by_other = $_POST['by_other'];


$date1 = date("m-d-Y");
$status = 0;



echo $name1.'<br />';
echo $address.'<br />';
echo $city.'<br />';
echo $state.'<br />';
echo $zip_code.'<br />';
echo $telephone.'<br />';
echo $email.'<br />';
echo $fiance.'<br />';
echo $wedding_date.'<br />';
echo $number_of_guest.'<br />';
echo $radio.'<br />';
echo $newspaper.'<br />';
echo $facebook.'<br />';
echo $website.'<br />';
echo $hear_by_other.'<br />';
echo $by_other.'<br />';
echo $date1.'<br />';
echo $status.'<br />';


$statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO arefin (name1,address,city,state,zip_code,telephone,email,fiance,wedding_date,number_of_guest,radio,newspaper,facebook,website,hear_by_other,by_other,date1,status) VALUES (:var1,:var2,:var3,:var4,:var5,:var6,:var7,:var8,:var9,:var10,:var11,:var12,:var13,:var14,:var15,:var16,:var17,:var18)');

$statement->bindParam(':var1',$name1);
$statement->bindParam(':var2',$address);
$statement->bindParam(':var3',$city);
$statement->bindParam(':var4',$state);
$statement->bindParam(':var5',$zip_code);
$statement->bindParam(':var6',$telephone);
$statement->bindParam(':var7',$email);
$statement->bindParam(':var8',$fiance);
$statement->bindParam(':var9',$wedding_date);
$statement->bindParam(':var10',$number_of_guest);
$statement->bindParam(':var11',$radio);
$statement->bindParam(':var12',$newspaper);
$statement->bindParam(':var13',$facebook);
$statement->bindParam(':var14',$website);
$statement->bindParam(':var15',$hear_by_other);
$statement->bindParam(':var16',$by_other);
$statement->bindParam(':var17',$date1);
$statement->bindParam(':var18',$status);
$statement->execute();

?>
```

My config.php File is here:

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'arefinDB';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname}", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $conn = $pdo;
}
catch( PDOException $excepiton ) {
    echo "Connection error :" . $excepiton->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Database Table looks like:
[image]

Comment: Is `date1` a real MySQL DATE/DATETIME column? If so, the date format is incorrect. Should be `Y-m-d`, not `m-d-Y`.

Comment: Have you tried adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to make sure you capture all errors?

Comment: Ah so it's a `varchar()` (which is not recommended, by the way - should be a `DATE`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add proper error handling so that you know exactly what is failing and why.

First you need to tell PDO to throw exceptions:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname}", $dbuser, $dbpass);
// add this:
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Then you can wrap your database operations in a `try` - `catch` block:

```
try
{
  $statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO arefin (name1,address,city,state,zip_code,telephone,email,fiance,wedding_date,number_of_guest,radio,newspaper,facebook,website,hear_by_other,by_other,date1,status) VALUES (:var1,:var2,:var3,:var4,:var5,:var6,:var7,:var8,:var9,:var10,:var11,:var12,:var13,:var14,:var15,:var16,:var17,:var18)');

  $statement->bindParam(':var1',$name1);
  // etc.

  $statement->execute();
}
catch ( PDOException $exception )
{
    echo "PDO error :" . $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Too long for a comment, but it should help to solve the problem...

Comment: Thanks jeroen, it is showing me this error now: `PDO error :SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'facebook' cannot be null`

Comment: @Engr Arefin Let me guess, `facebook` is a checkbox? Non-checked checkboxes do not get sent to the server, so `$_POST['facebook']` is not set / `NULL`. You should check if your checkboxes are set and add an empty value if not.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this way, may be:

```
$statement->execute(array(':var1'=>$name1,
                  ':var2'=>$address));
```

The reason I am asking you to do this is:

1. It occupies less amount of code.
2. It is easier than the previous one.

#### And what about `wedding_date`?

Are you inserting in the correct format?

Comment: And maybe you would like to explain why it should make any difference to use the array param to `execute()` instead of the individual `bindParam()` calls.

Comment: I added the image of my database table. Please check again my code.

Comment: @EngrArefin Please add also your `var_dump($_POST)`, please. :) What is the error you are getting when you execute the query?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, where should i add var_dump($_POST) ? I get no error message. echo are printing all data well. But only data are not inserting into the database.

Comment: After this line: `include 'includes/config.php';`