# inserting date using PDO and php

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to insert into a table, I have managed this using the same syntax for another query but this fails, the only difference is that this contains date information. Can anyone spot the problem?

The date is in this format: 2016-07-07.

```
try {
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO excavation.contexts_spatial 
    (area_easting, 
    area_northing, 
    context_number, 
    open_date,
    close_date,
    excavation_method,
    contamination,
    zooarchaeology_comments,
    ceramic_comments) VALUES (
    :area_easting, 
    :area_northing, 
    :context_number, 
    :open_date, 
    :close_date, 
    :excavation_method,
    :contamination,
    :zooarchaeology_comments,
    :ceramic_comments)";

$stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);

// prepare sql and bind parameters
$stmt2->bindParam(':area_easting', $area_easting, PDO::PARAM_INT);       
$stmt2->bindParam(':area_northing', $area_northing, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt2->bindParam(':context_number', $nextContext, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt2->bindParam(':open_date', $open_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->bindParam(':close_date', $close_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->bindParam(':excavation_method', $excavation_method, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->bindParam(':contamination', $contamination, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->bindParam(':zooarchaeology_comments', $excavation_method, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->bindParam(':ceramic_comments', $excavation_method, PDO::PARAM_STR);

//$stmt2->execute(); 

// insert a row
$area_easting = $_SESSION['area_easting'];
$area_northing = $_SESSION['area_northing'];
$nextContext = $_SESSION['nextContext'];
$open_date = $_SESSION['dateOpen'];
$close_date = $_SESSION['dateClose'];
$excavation_method = $_SESSION['excavationMethod'];
$contamination = $_SESSION['contamination'];
$zooarchaeology_comments = $_SESSION['zooarchaeologyComments'];
$ceramic_comments = $_SESSION['ceramicComments'];
$stmt2->execute();

echo "New records created successfully in contexts spatial<br />";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
 echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to insert data into mysql database using PDO of PHP. But the data is not inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812832/i-want-to-insert-data-into-mysql-database-using-pdo-of-php-but-the-data-is-not)

Comment: You are binding with uninitialised variables and executing before initialising the variables (and executing again). This is likely to be tripping a "not null" column constraint and failing the query.

Comment: Indeed: Error: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "open_date" violates not-null constraint

Comment: Well remove the first execute then.

Comment: first execute removed:
Error: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: ""

Comment: This is from the POST [dateOpen] => 2014-06-01

Comment: echo $_SESSION['dateOpen']; returns the date as 2014-06-01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing your statement before setting the variables. Remove **$stmt2->execute();** 
from below

```
$stmt2->bindParam(':ceramic_comments', $excavation_method, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt2->execute(); // REMOVE THIS LINE

// insert a row
$area_easting = $_SESSION['area_easting'];
```

Comment: Thankyou, this was noted in the above comments, so I have commented this line. The issue now is the date: Error: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: ""

Comment: Did you use datepicker for selection of date in your form or are you entering it manually in input field?